# Checkbox status not being found with "is_selected"

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to see if a check box is checked (using Selenium Python), using the following code:

```
checkboxclick = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(mycheckbox)
if checkboxclick.is_selected == True:
        cb_satus = True
```

The problem is that "checkboxclick.is_selected" returns False even when the checkbox is checked.
Is there another way to read if it's checked?

```
<input id="smsaccount-general-settings-prepend-prefix-always" 
ng-model="model.accountSettings.networkLookupOptions.prependPrefixAlways" 
type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0 
ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" checkbox-input="">
```

Comment: It might be better to show your what value you assign to `mycheckbox`.

Comment: Small off-topic note... The `== True` isn't needed since you'd be doing a boolean v booelan comparison and may actually hinder you, just use `if checkboxclick.is_selected:`

Answer (score 1):

Change Code From :

```
if checkboxclick.is_selected == True:
    cb_satus = True
```

To :

```
if checkboxclick.is_selected() == True:
    cb_satus = True
```

Comment: I still get the same result, cb_status = False

Comment: Could you please add the following code.
  ` print checkboxclick.is_selected()`
    checkboxclick.click()    print checkboxclick.is_selected()

Comment: That prints out "False"